# Pygame Hangman Easier Way To Generate New Words? Instead Of Making Another Main Loop

Tags: python, pygame

so I am working on this hangman game and I am trying to make new generated fruit names instead of copying the first main loop and pasting it again I feel like that would be to much code and I will have a lot of issues is there a way  [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/a22a5453a44f23d1f935b460208dad67) < this is my fruit11() right now it only works for the word Apple is there a way I could make it so when I finish the word apple it resets and generates a new word instead of copying the whole main loop and pasting it again that would be so much code and will be alot of things to change thank YOU!

if I copy this and make a new loop for my second word like my first word right now is "apple" if I copy this main loop and make a new one then I would have thousands of lines of code I just want to know if there is an easy way to make new words for my hangman

```
def lose_screen():
    

    timer = 0
    # the background image
    bg = pygame.image.load("lose.png")


    FPS = 50
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    def redraw():
        window.blit(bg,(0,0))


                

                    


 
    intro = True
    while intro:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                intro = False
                pygame.quit()
        timer += 1
        if timer >= 120:
            fruit11()



        redraw()
        clock.tick(FPS)


        pygame.display.update()






def player1_win():
    

    timer = 0
    # the background image
    bg = pygame.image.load("player1win.png")


    FPS = 50
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    def redraw():
        window.blit(bg,(0,0))


                

                    


 
    intro = True
    while intro:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                intro = False
                pygame.quit()
        timer += 1
        if timer >= 120:
            fruit11()



        redraw()
        clock.tick(FPS)


        pygame.display.update()




def player2_win():
    

    timer = 0
    # the background image
    bg = pygame.image.load("player2win.png")


    FPS = 50
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    def redraw():
        window.blit(bg,(0,0))


                

                    


 
    intro = True
    while intro:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                intro = False
                pygame.quit()
        timer += 1
        if timer >= 120:
            fruit11()



        redraw()
        clock.tick(FPS)


        pygame.display.update()




def fruit11():

    class partic:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        def draw(self,DrawX,DrawY):
            self.rect.topleft = (DrawX,DrawY)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect,2)

    white = (255,255,255)            
    partic1 = partic(500,500,50,50,white)


    colors = (0, 0, 0)
    greenbutton0 = button((colors),60,600,50,50, 'A')
    greenbutton1 = button((colors),140,600,50,50, 'C')
    greenbutton2 = button((colors),220,600,50,50, 'F')
    greenbutton3 = button((colors),300,600,50,50, 'P')
    greenbutton4 = button((colors),380,600,50,50, 'D')
    greenbutton5 = button((colors),60,660,50,50, 'U')
    greenbutton6 = button((colors),140,660,50,50, 'L')
    greenbutton7 = button((colors),220,660,50,50, 'P')
    greenbutton8 = button((colors),300,660,50,50, 'N')
    greenbutton9 = button((colors),380,660,50,50, 'H')

    greenbutton10 = button((colors),60,720,50,50, 'X')
    greenbutton11 = button((colors),140,720,50,50, 'R')
    greenbutton12 = button((colors),220,720,50,50, 'D')
    greenbutton13 = button((colors),300,720,50,50, 'E')
    greenbutton14 = button((colors),380,720,50,50, 'O')

    menu_button = button((colors),390,210,150,50, "")
    buttons = [greenbutton0,greenbutton1,greenbutton2,greenbutton3,greenbutton4,greenbutton5,greenbutton6,greenbutton7,greenbutton8,greenbutton9,greenbutton10,greenbutton11,greenbutton12,greenbutton13,greenbutton14]




            
    font = pygame.font.Font("times.ttf", 40)
    scor = 0
    scoretext = font.render("" + str(scor), True, (255,255,255))
    scorerect = scoretext.get_rect()
    scorerect.center = ((450,180))


    font = pygame.font.Font("times.ttf", 40)
    sco = 0
    scoretex = font.render("" + str(sco), True, (255,255,255))
    scorerec = scoretex.get_rect()
    scorerec.center = ((50,180))

    nor = pygame.image.load("lose.png")


    bg = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
    bg2 = pygame.image.load("player2.png")

    stickhead = pygame.image.load("nos.png")
    stickbody = pygame.image.load("bod.png")
    stickleg = pygame.image.load("leg2.png")
    stickleg2 = pygame.image.load("leg1.png")
    arm = pygame.image.load("bod2.png")
    arm2 = pygame.image.load("bod3.png")
    score = 0
    score2 = 0
    particles = []
    def redraw():
        

        window.blit(bg,(0,0))


        if score == 1 or score == 3 or score == 5 or score == 7 or score == 9 or score == 11 or score == 14 or score == 15:
            window.blit(bg2,(0,0))

        if score == 2 or score == 4 or score == 6 or score == 8 or score == 10 or score == 12 or score == 14 or score == 16:
            window.blit(bg,(0,0))


        
        
        for button in buttons:
            button.draw(window)


        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for button in buttons:
            if button.isOver(pos):
                partic1.draw(button.x,button.y)



        if score2 >= 1:
            for button in buttons:
                if button.x == 1040:
                    window.blit(stickhead,(170,240))

        if score2 >= 2:
            for button in buttons:
                if button.x == 1040:
                    window.blit(stickbody,(180,300))

        if score2 >= 3:
            for button in buttons:
                if button.x == 1040:
                    window.blit(stickleg,(180,360))

        if score2 >= 4:
            for button in buttons:
                if button.x == 1040:
                    window.blit(stickleg2,(150,360))

        if score2 >= 5:
            for button in buttons:
                if button.x == 1040:
                    window.blit(arm,(170,280))

        if score2 >= 6:
            for button in buttons:
                if button.x == 1040:
                    window.blit(arm2,(150,280))

        window.blit(scoretext,scorerect)
        window.blit(scoretex,scorerec)
    # our main loop


            
                    
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        # what happens if our mouse clicks the button
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


    
                    
                # back to game
                if menu_button.isOver(pos):
                    game_intro()

            
                
                if greenbutton0.isOver(pos) and greenbutton0.y == 600:
                    greenbutton0.y = 490
                    greenbutton0.x = 34
                    score += 1

                    
                    if score == 1 or score == 3 or score == 5 or score == 7 or score == 9 or score == 11 or score == 14 or score == 15:
                        scor += 1
                        scoretext = font.render("" + str(scor), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerect.center = ((450,180))


                    if score == 2 or score == 4 or score == 6 or score == 8 or score == 10 or score == 12 or score == 14 or score == 16:
                        sco += 1
                        scoretex = font.render("" + str(sco), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerec.center = ((50,180))
    
                    
                if greenbutton7.isOver(pos) and greenbutton7.y == 660:
                    greenbutton7.y = 490
                    greenbutton7.x = 120
                    score += 1

                    if score == 1 or score == 3 or score == 5 or score == 7 or score == 9 or score == 11 or score == 14 or score == 15:
                        scor += 1
                        scoretext = font.render("" + str(scor), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerect.center = ((450,180))


                    if score == 2 or score == 4 or score == 6 or score == 8 or score == 10 or score == 12 or score == 14 or score == 16:
                        sco += 1
                        scoretex = font.render("" + str(sco), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerec.center = ((50,180))

                   
                    
                if greenbutton3.isOver(pos) and greenbutton3.y == 600:
                    greenbutton3.y = 490
                    greenbutton3.x = 200
                    score += 1

                    if score == 1 or score == 3 or score == 5 or score == 7 or score == 9 or score == 11 or score == 14 or score == 15:
                        scor += 1
                        scoretext = font.render("" + str(scor), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerect.center = ((450,180))


                    if score == 2 or score == 4 or score == 6 or score == 8 or score == 10 or score == 12 or score == 14 or score == 16:
                        sco += 1
                        scoretex = font.render("" + str(sco), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerec.center = ((50,180))

     
                if greenbutton6.isOver(pos) and greenbutton6.y == 660:
                    greenbutton6.y = 490
                    greenbutton6.x = 300
                    score += 1

                    if score == 1 or score == 3 or score == 5 or score == 7 or score == 9 or score == 11 or score == 14 or score == 15:
                        scor += 1
                        scoretext = font.render("" + str(scor), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerect.center = ((450,180))


                    if score == 2 or score == 4 or score == 6 or score == 8 or score == 10 or score == 12 or score == 14 or score == 16:
                        sco += 1
                        scoretex = font.render("" + str(sco), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerec.center = ((50,180))

                    

                if greenbutton13.isOver(pos) and greenbutton13.y == 720:
                    greenbutton13.y = 490
                    greenbutton13.x = 380
                    score += 1

                    if score == 1 or score == 3 or score == 5 or score == 7 or score == 9 or score == 11 or score == 14 or score == 15:
                        scor += 1
                        scoretext = font.render("" + str(scor), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerect.center = ((450,180))


                    if score == 2 or score == 4 or score == 6 or score == 8 or score == 10 or score == 12 or score == 14 or score == 16:
                        sco += 1
                        scoretex = font.render("" + str(sco), True, (255,255,255))
                        scorerec.center = ((50,180))                    

 

                     

                if greenbutton1.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton1.x = 1040
                    
                if greenbutton2.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton2.x = 1040
                    
                if greenbutton4.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton4.x = 1040
                    
                if greenbutton5.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton5.x = 1040
                    
                    
                if greenbutton8.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton8.x = 1040
                    
                if greenbutton9.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton9.x = 1040
                    
                if greenbutton10.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton10.x = 1040
                    
                if greenbutton11.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton11.x = 1040
                    
                if greenbutton12.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score +=1 
                    greenbutton12.x = 1040
                    
                    
                if greenbutton14.isOver(pos):
                    score2 += 1
                    score += 1 
                    greenbutton14.x = 1040


        if score2 == 6:
            lose_screen()


        if greenbutton0.y == 490 and greenbutton7.y == 490 and greenbutton3.y == 490 and greenbutton6.y == 490 and greenbutton13.y == 490:
            if sco > scor:
                player1_win()
                
        if greenbutton0.y == 490 and greenbutton7.y == 490 and greenbutton3.y == 490 and greenbutton6.y == 490 and greenbutton13.y == 490:
            if sco < scor:
                player2_win()
                        


        redraw()
        pygame.display.update()
        
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I cannot find the word "apple" in your code. Put the code to a function and call the function.

Comment: Its not a word apple i have bunch have buttons that have defferent  letters wdym?

Comment: What is the purpose of changing the button co-ordinates in the `if` clauses? E.g.: `if greenbutton7.isOver(pos) and greenbutton7.y == 660:` then `greenbutton7` `x` and `y` are changed. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for the game [Hangman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)), how can we process each player's turn as a function?  The player supplies a letter, and we return "correct", "fail" and "duplicate" (which is probably should also be a fail).

```
def hangmanGuess( secret_word, guess_letter, used_letters ):
    """ Given a guess, return "correct" if the letter is in the secret, but
        already used.  Return "fail" if the letter is not in the secret, and
        "duplicate" for a letter already used (pass or fail) """
    result = "fail"
    ### Is the letter in the secret?
    if ( guess_letter.lower() in used_letters ):
        result = "duplicate"
    elif ( guess_letter.lower() in secret_word.lower() ):
        result = "correct"
    return result
```

So now we can easily check the result.

Something else we need to display the secret, with all the non-guessed letters "blanked out".  I think underscores will be good for this.  Some words also have spaces, and dashes, but we don't want to have to guess those.

```
INVALID_LETTERS=' ~!@#$%^&*()-_+=[{]}|\:;\'\"?/,.<>1234567890'  # not used for guesses

def getWordString( secret_word, used_letters, hide_character='_' ):
    """ Given a secret, hide any letters that are not already used,
        by replacing it with hide_character.  Returns a copy of the
        secret with all known letters shown """
    result = ''
    for letter in secret_word:
        # Anything that's guessed already, or not-a-letter is copied through
        if ( letter.lower() in used_letters or letter.lower() in INVALID_LETTERS ):
            result += letter
        else:
            result += hide_character
    return result
```

And that's about it.  Now we can just loop around, printing the guessed-word so far, then fetching input from the user, and checking whether the guess is correct.  If they tried too many times, that's game over.  If they win, reset everything and try again.

So putting all that together:

```
python3 ./handman.py 
[ _______ ]
Guess a Letter: a
[ _______ ]
Guess a Letter: b
[ B______ ]
Guess a Letter: c
[ B______ ]
Guess a Letter: l
[ B_ll___ ]
Guess a Letter: u
[ Bull___ ]
Guess a Letter: s
[ Bull___ ]
Guess a Letter: t
[ Bull___ ]
Guess a Letter: o
[ Bull_o_ ]
Guess a Letter: f
[ Bull_o_ ]
Guess a Letter: d
[ Bulldo_ ]
Guess a Letter: g
[Bulldog]
*** GAME WON ***
```

And the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import random

INVALID_LETTERS=' ~!@#$%^&*()-_+=[{]}|\:;\'\"?/,.<>1234567890'  # not used for guesses

def hangmanGuess( secret_word, guess_letter, used_letters ):
    """ Given a guess, return "correct" if the letter is in the secret, but
        already used.  Return "fail" if the letter is not in the secret, and
        "duplicate" for a letter already used (pass or fail) """
    result = "fail"
    ### Is the letter in the secret?
    if ( guess_letter in used_letters ):
        result = "duplicate"
    elif ( guess_letter in secret_word.lower() ):
        result = "correct"
    return result


def getWordString( secret_word, used_letters, hide_character='_' ):
    """ Given a secret, hide any letters that are not already used,
        by replacing it with hide_character.  Returns a copy of the
        secret with all known letters shown """
    result = ''
    for letter in secret_word:
        # Anything that's guessed already, or not-a-letter is copied through
        if ( letter.lower() in used_letters or letter.lower() in INVALID_LETTERS ):
            result += letter
        else:
            result += hide_character
    return result

def getPlainWord( secret_word ):
    """ Return the word without any punctuation or digits (etc.) """
    cleaned_word = secret_word.translate( str.maketrans( '', '', INVALID_LETTERS ) )
    return cleaned_word


all_words = [ 'Aardvark', 'Abyssinian', 'Adelie Penguin', 'Affenpinscher', 'Afghan Hound', 'African Bush Elephant', 'African Civet', 'African Clawed Frog', 'African Forest Elephant', 'African Palm Civet', 'African Penguin', 'African Tree Toad', 'African Wild Dog', 'Ainu Dog', 'Airedale Terrier', 'Akbash', 'Akita', 'Alaskan Malamute', 'AlbatrossBaboon', 'Bactrian Camel', 'Badger', 'Baiji', 'Balinese', 'Banded Palm Civet', 'Bandicoot', 'Barb', 'Barn Owl', 'Barnacle', 'Barracuda', 'Barramundi Fish', 'Basenji Dog', 'Basking Shark', 'Basset Hound', 'Bat', 'Bavarian Mountain Hound', 'Beagle', 'Bear', 'Bearded Collie', 'Bearded Dragon', 'Beaver', 'Bedlington Terrier', 'Beetle', 'Beluga Sturgeon', 'Bengal Tiger', 'Bernese Mountain Dog', 'Bichon Frise', 'Binturong', 'Bird', 'Birds Of Paradise', 'Birman', 'Bison', 'Black Marlin', 'Black Rhinoceros', 'Black Russian Terrier', 'Black Widow Spider', 'Blobfish', 'Bloodhound', 'Blue Jay', 'Blue Lacy Dog', 'Blue Whale', 'Bluetick Coonhound', 'Bobcat', 'Bolognese Dog', 'Bombay', 'Bongo', 'Bonito Fish', 'Bonobo', 'Booby', 'Border Collie', 'Border Terrier', 'Bornean Orang-utan', 'Borneo Elephant', 'Boston Terrier', 'Bottlenose Dolphin', 'Bowhead Whale', 'Boxer Dog', 'Boykin Spaniel', 'Brazilian Terrier', 'British Timber', 'Brown Bear', 'Budgerigar', 'Buffalo', 'Bull Shark', 'Bull Terrier', 'Bulldog', 'Bullfrog', 'Bullmastiff', 'Bumblebee', 'Burmese', 'Burrowing Frog', 'Butterfly', 'Butterfly Fish', 'Aldabra Giant Tortoise', 'Alligator', 'Alpaca', 'Amur Leopard', 'Anatolian Shepherd Dog', 'Angelfish', 'Ant', 'Anteater', 'Antelope', 'Appenzeller Dog', 'Arctic Fox', 'Arctic Hare', 'Arctic Wolf', 'Armadillo', 'Asian Elephant', 'Asian Giant Hornet', 'Asian Palm Civet', 'Asiatic Black Bear', 'Aurochs', 'Cattle Dog', 'Kelpie Dog', 'Avocet', 'Axolotl', 'Aye Aye', 'Caiman', 'Caiman Lizard', 'Cairn Terrier', 'Camel', 'Camel Spider', 'Canaan Dog', 'Canadian Eskimo Dog', 'Capybara', 'Caracal', 'Carolina Dog', 'Cassowary', 'Cat', 'Caterpillar', 'Catfish', 'Cavalier King Charles Spaniel', 'Centipede', 'Cesky Fousek', 'Chameleon', 'Chamois', 'Cheetah', 'Chesapeake Bay Retriever', 'Chicken', 'Chihuahua', 'Chimaera', 'Chimpanzee', 'Chinchilla', 'Chinese Crested Dog', 'Chinook', 'Chinstrap Penguin', 'Chipmunk', 'Chow Chow', 'Cichlid', 'Clouded Leopard', 'Clown Fish', 'Clumber Spaniel', 'Coati', 'Cockatoo', 'Cockroach', 'Collared Peccary', 'Collie', 'Colossal Squid', 'Common Buzzard', 'Common Frog', 'Common Loon', 'Common Toad', 'Coral', 'Cotton-top Tamarin', 'Cougar', 'Cow', 'Coyote', 'Crab', 'Crab-Eating Macaque', 'Crane', 'Crested Penguin', 'Crocodile', 'Cross River Gorilla', 'Curly Coated Retriever', 'Cuscus', 'Cuttlefish', 'Dachshund', 'Dalmatian', 'Darwin’s Frog', 'Deer', 'Desert Tortoise', 'Deutsche Bracke', 'Dhole', 'Dingo', 'Discus', 'Doberman Pinscher', 'Dodo', 'Dog', 'Dogo Argentino', 'Dogue De Bordeaux', 'Dolphin', 'Donkey', 'Dormouse', 'Dragonfish', 'Dragonfly', 'Drever', 'Drum Fish', 'Duck', 'Dugong', 'Dunker', 'Dusky Dolphin', 'Dwarf Crocodile', 'Eagle', 'Earwig', 'Eastern Gorilla', 'Eastern Lowland Gorilla', 'Echidna', 'Edible Frog', 'Egyptian Mau', 'Electric Eel', 'Elephant', 'Elephant Seal', 'Elephant Shrew', 'Emperor Penguin', 'Emperor Tamarin', 'Emu', 'English Cocker Spaniel', 'English Shepherd', 'English Springer Spaniel', 'Entlebucher Mountain Dog', 'Epagneul Pont Audemer', 'Ermine', 'Eskimo Dog', 'Estrela Mountain Dog' ]


used_letters   = []
failed_letters = 0
pass_letters   = 0
secret_word    = random.choice( all_words )
target_size    = len( getPlainWord( secret_word ) )  # remove punctuation from guess-count

finished = False
while not finished:

    display_word = getWordString( secret_word, used_letters )
    print( "[ %s ]" % ( display_word ) )

    letter = input( "Guess a Letter: " )
    letter = letter.lower().strip()
    if ( len( letter ) != 1 ):
        print( "Please enter only a single letter!" )
    else:
        guess_result = hangmanGuess( secret_word, letter, used_letters )
        if ( guess_result != "duplicate" ):
            used_letters.append( letter )
            if ( guess_result == "fail" ):
                failed_letters += 1     
            else:
                # guess was correct
                count = secret_word.lower().count( letter )
                pass_letters += count

    # Is the game over?
    if ( failed_letters > 10 ):
        print( "* GAME OVER * " )
        finished = True
    elif ( pass_letters == target_size ):
        print( "[%s]" % ( secret_word ) )
        print( "*** GAME WON ***\n" )
        # Restart
        used_letters   = []
        failed_letters = 0
        pass_letters   = 0
        secret_word    = random.choice( all_words )
        target_size    = len( getPlainWord( secret_word ) ) # remove punctuation from guess-count
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at it for a minute.  I don't see where words are even being generated... apple?

You should learn how to use the `%` modulo operator.  It gives you the remainder after division, so

> "four divided by 2 has no remainder" `4 % 2 = 0`
> "five divided by two has a remainder of 1" `5 % 2 = 1`

thus, quickly being able to tell if a number is even or odd.  This would greatly reduce those long lines of `if score == 1 or score == 3 or score == 5` ...
https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_oper_mod

Comment: This is an answer, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: I realize, but comments are too tiny for this amount of information.